# Conflicting key types in different subprojects

Tags: sbt

I have a project with two subprojects. In one, I want to use [sbt-docker](https://github.com/marcuslonnberg/sbt-docker), in the other, [sbt-native-packager](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager). However, they both define a key `dockerCmd` with different types (`String` and `Seq[String]` respectively), so loading the project fails:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Some keys were defined with the same name but different types: 'dockerCmd' (scala.collection.Seq[java.lang.String], java.lang.String)
```

Is there a way around this easier than modifying the plugins to agree on the types?

Comment: Nope, one of the pitfalls of sbt is the lack of key name spaces. Split it into two independent projects or use only one of the two plugins. Or submit PRs to make them play nicely together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Plugins Best Practices](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Plugins-Best-Practices.html#Key+naming+convention%3A+Use+prefix):

> ### Key naming convention: Use prefix
>
> Sometimes, you need a new key, because there is no existing sbt key. In this case, use a plugin-specific prefix.